# I found a motor/generator thing at my school's storage. I was wondering if anyone could identify it

Tags: motor, generator

Side view:
[image: side view]
Commutator side:
[image: commutator side]
Slip ring side:
[image: slip ring side]

I'm not sure what this is because it has both commutator segments and slip rings. It didn't have anything else with it. I'm guessing it has something to do with AC generation.

Comment: Probably a lecture model.  Possibly able to operate in multiple modes.  No stator is pictured; perhaps you mean the slip rings on the left.

Comment: It would be interesting to see this from other angles. It is very likely something that can be configured to be more than one type of machine for student demonstration or laboratory use. Parts are missing. It may have been useful to demonstrate types of machines that are no longer studied or used.

Comment: Im not sure how to add more images so ill give you this link:http://imgur.com/VPPKvOy
http://imgur.com/Gb60Ihp
http://imgur.com/SusFnzW
http://imgur.com/vwyYtFe

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to identify something, it is always a good idea to mention anything that is written on it. Better yet, use what is found as a search term in your own search. Also, ask someone where the item was found. Have you asked at your school: "Who is Dr. Clemenz? Is he available to explain this equipment?".

Here is a picture from [Liceo Classico “Vittorio Alfieri”](https://www.istitutovalfieri.edu.it/valfieri/la-scuola/presentazione/) (an Italian classical high school) that shows the rotor that you found installed in a machine

[image]

The machine design is very unusual, but it appears to be capable of operating as a DC motor or generator with a commutator and also as a 3-phase AC, wound-rotor synchronous machine. There are also alternative rotors that can be possible be used with the same stator or with another stator. From the same source:

[image]

These items are in [a larger Physics collection the the Liceo](http://www.istitutovalfieri.edu.it/labscienze/elettromagnetismo.htm) that contains these items, within [an even larger collection of scientific equipment at the Liceo](http://www.istitutovalfieri.edu.it/labscienze/).